# SVG dashed path animation

Tags: animation, svg, path

How can I change the line to dashed line and still have the animation? I tried so many things but I couldn't figure it out:

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #4CAF50; /* Green color for the success path */
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <path class="path" d="M0,25
    Q25,10 50,25
    Q75,40 100,25"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assume your path is 100px long.* You can make a `stroke-dasharray` that has 100px worth of a dashed pattern followed by a 100px (or more) gap, e.g:

```
16 5 16 5 16 5 16 5 16  101
^-- 100px pattern ---^  ^-- At least 100px gap
```

If you start with a `stroke-dashoffset` of 100, you'll only see the gap, i.e. nothing. If you then slowly animate the offset to 0, the dashed pattern will move in from the left.

*In such cases, it's is easer to tell the browser to assume the path is a given length too, rather than calculate its actual length. We can do that with the `pathLength` attribute.*

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #4CAF50;
  /* Green color for the success path */
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 16 5 16 5 16 5 16 5 16 101;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
    <path class="path" pathLength="100"
          d="M0,25  Q25,10 50,25  Q75,40 100,25" />
</svg>
```